# Динамически добавлять TextView в LinearLayout, который является заготовкой для ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, adapter

Здравствуйте! 
Помогите, пожалуйста, решить проблему.
Пробую реализовать ListView так, как показано в примере: http://www.heikkitoivonen.net/blog/2009/02/15/multicolumn-listview-in-android/

Все достаточно просто и понятно. При использовании LinearLayout с уже имеющимися TextView в xml-файле проблем не возникает. Однако мне надо, чтобы в этот LinearLayout можно было добавить TextView программно.
Я пишу вот так:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.item);
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    myLL = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.itemlistview);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    txt = new TextView(this);
    txt.setId(5);
    txt.setLayoutParams(params);
    myLL.addView(txt);
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_test_table, null, true);

    ListView list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.table);       
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> myList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("время","00:00");
    myList.add(map);
    map=new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("время", "01:00");
    myList.add(map);
    SimpleAdapter spisok = new SimpleAdapter(this, myList, myLL.getId(), new String[]{"время"}, new int[]{5});
    list.setAdapter(spisok);
}
```

Однако в myLL нет TextView, который я добавила. Соответственно, адаптер его тоже не видит.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, что делать?

Answer (score 1):

В вашем случае его не нужно генерировать, сделайте обычный файл разметки, если все же задача  шире чем Вы  описали и генерировать что то нужно то делайте это в адапторе

---

[Кастомизация списков](http://habrahabr.ru/post/133575/) если кратко то  создайте вой адаптер  унаследованный от обычного (не факт что Вам нужен SimpleAdapter, вполне может подойти и ArrayAdapter) перегрузите getView и в нем уже либо генерируйте, либо берите из файлов разметки

Comment: Дело в том, что я же не знаю заранее, сколько у меня будет TextView находиться на LinearLayout.

А могли бы вы подсказать, как использовать адаптер для добавления TextView на LinearLayout?

Comment: изменил ответ

Comment: В той ссылке, что вы привели, написано:

     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);

Обратите внимание на 2 последние строки. TextView и ImageView находятся в разметке, а не программно добавлены.

Comment: В любом случае получается новый view - Вы просто меньше играетесь с оформлением и прочими мелочами, да и не принцыпиально  ─ хотите создовайте полностью програмно, хотите с использованием разметки - задача добавлять динамически, каким образом это делать решать Вам, в ссылке просто показан пример адаптера

Answer (score 1):

ну, а что мешает сделать

```
 rowView.addView(new TextView(context));
```

, где `new TextView(context)` - вью, который нужно добавить динамически?

Comment: Так я так и пишу. 

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    txt = new TextView(this);
    txt.setId(5);
    txt.setLayoutParams(params);
    myLL.addView(txt);
    //...
    SimpleAdapter spisok = new SimpleAdapter(this, myList, myLL.getId(), new String[]{"время"}, new int[]{5});
    list.setAdapter(spisok);

Однако, когда передаю в конструктор адаптера и присваиваю адаптер Листу, ничего не происходит

Comment: ну, вы же это делаете в Активити, а не в адаптере!

Comment: И в адаптере я пробую добавить.
Пишу такой же код, как и в статье: http://habrahabr.ru/post/133575/
Пункт "Пример: ListActivity с гибким шаблоном".
Только не      TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);

А
    LinearLayout row = (LinearLayout) rowView;
  
  TextView txt = new TextView(context);
  txt.setId(5);
  txt.setText("Hello, World!");
  txt.setLayoutParams(params);
  row.addView(txt);
  return row;

Comment: и таким образом TextView не добавляется...?    
Сейчас быстро соберу проект, и попробую сам.

Comment: У меня в getView даже не заходит...

Comment: ну, так это совсем другое дело...
(Только что проверил - добавляется TextView динамически)
Я думаю, вы не правильно переопределили методы у адаптера, или не правильно устанавливаете адаптер у ListView. В любом случае, "нужно больше кода"
Если хотите, я могу вам сбросить на почту(или куда хотите) свой код, что я только что набросал, и который добавляет динамически правильно, или можете вы мне на почту(metalurgus@mail.ru) сбросить свой код, и я посмотрю его, может найду, в чем ошибка

Comment: Я Вам скинула свои файлы.
Буду признательна, если отправите свой код.